# Does this particular NVMe disk work in Storage Spaces on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: storage-spaces

HPE Proliant DL380 Gen10 with Windows Server 2019 Standard.

I want to use NVMe disks with Storage Spaces (not Direct aka S2D).

The disk is HPE P50228-B21 3.2TB NVMe Gen4 High Performance Mixed Use SFF SCN U.3 PM1735a SSD.

Does Storage Spaces support this disk? If not, what other way can be used to create a big pool?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-direct-hardware-requirements The controller needs to support HBA mode and there is a minimum number required, but generally yes.

Comment: i am talking about storage spaces..not storage space direct(S2D)..these are the bus that works according to Microsoft : Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)
- Serial Advanced Technology Attachment (SATA)
- iSCSI and Fibre Channel Controllers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you’ll be fine. HPE has no NVMe capable RAID controllers, which leaves software RAID as your only option. If you don’t want S/S you can enable Hyper-V role, spawn some Linux virtual machine, pass-thru your disks there and pool them with either ZFS or Linux software RAID. Both are way more reliable compared to what Microsoft has to offer with Storage Spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The HPE P50228-B21 3.2TB NVMe Gen4 High Performance Mixed Use SFF SCN U.3 PM1735a SSD should work with Storage Spaces on Windows Server 2019 Standard. However, I'm not entirely sure as I haven't used it before.

Storage Spaces supports various types of disks, including NVMe drives like the one you mentioned. You should be able to create a storage pool using this disk without any issues.

If you encounter any problems or if Storage Spaces doesn't recognize the disk, you might need to check if the disk is properly installed and configured in your server. However, in most cases, it should work just fine for creating a storage pool.

If you're looking for an alternative way to create a storage pool, you could consider using hardware RAID controllers or software RAID solutions, although Storage Spaces is a popular and reliable option for Windows Server environments.

Regarding HPE products, I don't have much experience with them, but I have used StoneFly products before and found them reliable. You may want to check them out before making a decision.

If you need suggestions for other brands or products, I'm happy to do some research for you based on my experience.

Thank you.